# Paypal button customization boostrap like

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, paypal, express-checkout

I need to insert 2 paypal button on a website: upgrade button and renew button.
According to new paypal reference, i used

```
paypal.Button.render
```

but customization is very limited.

```
 style: {
            label: 'checkout',
            size:  'small',    // small | medium | large | responsive
            shape: 'pill',     // pill | rect
            color: 'gold'      // gold | blue | silver | black
        },
```

i need to create the button as bootsrap

```
<button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> RENEW</button>
```

but paypal button is in iframe.

Is it possible using jQuery and css to get that effect?

Comment: You can't change style inside iframe. 
If iframe src domain name is same as parent site then you can change, but here you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

[Try use this js library](http://prototypejs.org/)

```
frame.$('button').addClassName('btn btn-danger');
```

hopes this helps u

Answer (score 0):

No for security reason, you cannot change any thing which is from other sources. Such as iframe.
If you need to do that, i remember in rest-API you can use server side coding to modify? Or don't use rest-API to make it, change to traditional form submit to paypal, that you can customize the button.